# Grunt and ImageMagick "responsive_images:dev": binaries can't be found

Tags: node.js, gruntjs, imagemagick

Please help me!!!

Some body knows how i can fix the following error on Mac Os X 10.9.5:

MacBook-Pro:demo usuario2$ grunt
Running "copy:dev" (copy) task
Created 5 directories, copied 10 files

Running "responsive_images:dev" (responsive_images) task

Running "connect:dev" (connect) task
Started connect web server on http://0.0.0.0:3000

Running "watch" task
Waiting...
^C
MacBook-Pro:demo usuario2$ grunt
Running "copy:dev" (copy) task
Created 5 directories, copied 10 files

Running "responsive_images:dev" (responsive_images) task
Warning: Could not execute GraphicsMagick/ImageMagick: gm "identify" "-ping" "-format" "%m:%T:%s" "src/assets/img/grunt-responsive-images.jpg" this most likely means the gm/convert binaries can't be found Use --force to continue.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This solved the very same issue for me.  I'm on Windows.  Mac users might want to try step #5 and 6.

1. Visit http://www.imagemagick.org/script/download.php#windows and download the exe file.
2. Run it on your local machine.
3. Select "Install legacy utilities (e.g. convert) on 'Select Additional Tasks' - see screenshot.
4. After installation is complete, type "grunt" from your project directory in cmd.
5. If it still does not work, open up command prompt as admin, navigate to project folder, and type "grunt" at command prompt.
6. If you get an error that says "grunt hasn't been installed locally to your project", make sure both grunt and grunt-cli are installed.

Edit:  Please ensure the engine is 'im' in your Gruntfile.js - as we're installing ImageMagick in the steps above.

```
grunt.initConfig({
    responsive_images: {
      dev: {
        options: {
          engine: 'im',
```

[image: Windows installation]